# Return Just An Element From A Mongodb Query (Newbie)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Is there a correct way to return just an element that matches the search query?

For example if I had

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5806d"),
    "title" : "vcvc",
    "description" : "vcvc",
    "lessons" : [
        {
            "lesson_body" : "Red Ball",
            "lesson_title" : "Red Ball",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5806s")
        },
        {
            "lesson_body" : "Green Ball",
            "lesson_title" : "Green Ball",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5806y")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

How would I be able to get just the following based on id?

```
{
 "lessons" : 
    {
        "lesson_body" : "Red Ball",
        "lesson_title" : "Red Ball",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5806s")
    }
}
```

Right now I just have the following, but it seems to just timeout

```
function(id, classLesson, callback){
    Class.find({'_id': classLesson._id}, {lessons: {$elemMatch: {_id: id}}})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify a query projection on the query, which specifies the fields to return from the database.

For example:

```
Class.find(
  { '_id': classLesson._id }, // query filter 
  { lessons: 1 } // query projection
)
```

Is your query supposed to be performing an $elemMath on the `lessons._id` field? Right now the $elemMatch in your code is placed in the projection portion of the query and is not being used to filter.